# How to change SharePoint Windows Authentication prompt times for login?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, iis-7, windows-authentication, spn

In my environment, my SharePoint 2010 is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7. The expected behavior after adding SPNs was that the user was prompted 3 times by default. How to configure the prompt times? maybe 2 or 5 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is decided in the browser, not in the server. Server returns HTTP401 status code in all of these requests, browser decides if the user should retry or not.

Anyway, when you have SPNs set up, passwords should work from the first time. It is worth rebooting the server after SPN setup.

Comment: Browser can decides if the user should retry or not,but I cannot find settings to change prompt times options in IE.

Comment: Any one knows where ot find settings to change prompt times options in IE?